# Using Node Web Kit GUI, how do you close a Screen?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, node-webkit

I'm trying to use Node Web Kits screen broadcasting to capture an image of the video an applying it to a canvas. I'm using angularjs to switch between the video and the canvas.

I'm opening and initializing the video by :

```
gui.Screen.init();
gui.Screen.chooseDesktopMedia(
    ["window", "screen"],
    function(streamId) {
        var vid_constraint = {
            mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                chromeMediaSourceId: streamId,
                maxWidth: 900,
                maxHeight: 600,
                minFrameRate: 1,
                maxFrameRate: 5
            },
            optional: []
        };
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
                audio: false,
                video: vid_constraint
            },
            function(stream) {

                console.log(stream, typeof URL.createObjectURL(stream));

                video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log('failure', error);
            });
    });
```

I then send an image of the Screen by applying it to a temp canvas and then switching the view using ng-if:

```
// first steps in the angular transition
    $scope.takePhoto = function() {
        console.log("draw")
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 900, 600);
        var sendVid = canvas.toDataURL();
        $rootScope.$broadcast("send video data", {show: false, videoImage : sendVid})
        gui.Screen.stop();
    };
```

Then when I try to initialize a new GUI it doesn't work. I get this error:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function
>      at new VideoCtrl (video-capture-directive.js:20)
>      at Object.invoke (angular.js:4476)
>      at extend.instance (angular.js:9127)
>      at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:8239)
>      at delayedNodeLinkFn (angular.js:8528)
>      at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7671)
>      at publicLinkFn (angular.js:7546)
>      at boundTranscludeFn (angular.js:7690)
>      at controllersBoundTransclude (angular.js:8307)
>      at Object.ngIfWatchAction [as fn] (angular.js:23994)

Why can't I just close the window and open a new one?